# How to get an index of a word in string array

Tags: c#

I want to get the index of a word in a string array.
for example, the sentence I will input is 'I love you.'
I have words[1] = love, how can I get the position of 'love' is 1? I could do it but just inside the if state. I want to bring it outside. Please help me.
This is my code.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sentence: ");
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        String[] words = a.Split(' ');
        List<string> verbs = new List<string>();
        verbs.Add("love");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < words.Length) {
            foreach (string verb in verbs) {
                if (words[i] == verb) {
                    int index = i;
                    Console.WriteLine(i);

                }
            } i++;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could do it but just inside the if state. I want to bring it outside.

Your code identifies the index correctly, all you need to do now is storing it for use outside the loop.

Make a list of `int`s, and call `Add` on it for the matches that you identify:

```
var indexes = new List<int>();
while (i < words.Length) {
    foreach (string verb in verbs) {
        if (words[i] == verb) {
            int index = i;
            indexes.Add(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

You can replace the inner loop with a call of `Contains` method, and the outer loop with a `for`:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i != words.Length ; i++) {
    if (verbs.Contains(words[i])) {
        indexes.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Finally, the whole sequence can be converted to a single LINQ query:

```
var indexes = words
    .Select((w,i) => new {w,i})
    .Where(p => verbs.Contains(p.w))
    .Select(p => p.i)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
var a = "I love you.";
var words = a.Split(' ');
var index = Array.IndexOf(words,"love");
Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int GetWordIndex(string WordOrigin, string GetWord)
{
    string[] words = WordOrigin.Split(' ');

    int Index = Array.IndexOf(words, GetWord);

    return Index;
}
```

assuming that you called the function as `GetWordIndex("Hello C# World", "C#");`, `WordOrigin` is `Hello C# World` and `GetWord` is `C#`

now according to the function:

1. `string[] words = WordsOrigin.Split(' ');` broke the string literal into an `array of strings` where the words would be split for every `spaces` in between them. so `Hello C# World` would then be broken down into `Hello`, `C#`, and `World`.
2. `int Index = Array.IndexOf(words, GetWord);` gets the Index of whatever `GetWord` is, according to the sample i provided, we are looking for the word `C#` from `Hello C# World` that is then splitted into an `Array of String`
3. `return Index;` simply returns whatever index it was located from